# how to display multiple markers on basis of multiple address on google map javascript instead of latitude and longitude

Tags: angular

Here I am using Angular 7. I am able to display the markers on map using of latitude and longitude. Is there any way to display multiple markers on map based on multiple addresses?

I am able to display one marker with one address using of geocode API in agm map, but not able to display multiple address with multiple marker on page init().

I have called 
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json' with parameter and API key. This API converts address to `lat` and `lng` so.

```
res["results"][0].geometry.location.lat
res["results"][0].geometry.location.lat
```

So I can fetch the detail for one address and display on agm map.

This is the structure that I am using in html

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="latitide" [longitude]="langtitude" [zoom]="zoom">

 </agm-map>
```

API Data :

```
this.markers = [
      {
          "Address": "London Business School",
          "title": "sharm el sheikh",
          "iconUrl": "yellow-dot",
          "label":"8/10"
      },
      {
          "Address":"University of Cambridge",
          "title": "Cairo",
          "iconUrl": "green-dot",
          "label":"7/10"
      },
      {
        "Address":"Imperial College London",
         "title": "Cairo",
        "iconUrl": "green-dot",
        "label":"7/10"
       },
       {
        "Address":"King's College London",
        "title": "Cairo",
        "iconUrl": "green-dot",
        "label":"7/10"
        }
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="latitide" [longitude]="langtitude" [zoom]="zoom">
     <agm-marker [latitude]="lat1" [longitude]="lng1"></agm-marker>
     <agm-marker [latitude]="lat2" [longitude]="lng2"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

you can also try looping if it is dynamic

```
  <agm-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of markers"
    [latitude]="marker.lat"
    [longitude]="marker.lng">
  </agm-marker>
```

Comment: but I have addresses in json data. how I can convert all the addresses to lat and lng and display in *ngFor loop.

Comment: Well, I suggest you update the question to include this and a sample of the data.

Comment: I have updated my question and there you can see API data in JSON form and addresses are given in json instead of lat and lng. that addresses I want to display in google map with the marker.

Comment: I don't see any longitude and latitude in your JSON data. People reading your question do not know anything apart from what you provide. However *ngFor="let marker of markers" should work on your JSON